# how to use audience-network-sdk-5.5.0 in react native in android app

Tags: react-native, expo, facebook-ads-api

import * as FacebookAds from 'expo-ads-facebook';
const { AdTriggerView, AdMediaView } = FacebookAds;

class AdComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      
        
        
          {this.props.nativeAd.bodyText}
        
      
    );
  }
}

export default FacebookAds.withNativeAd(AdComponent);

Comment: Welcome! Please see how to ask a question at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you  look at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook-ads/ ?

Comment: Its contain 5.1.1